# Values of lambda expressions and associativity

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus

Can someone tell me what are the results of these lambda expressions when substitute `x=5`?

```
a) λx. ((λx.x+1) x)

b) (λx. (λx.x+1)) x
```

Here is what I think.

a) λx. (λx.x+1) x)5 = (λx.x+1) 5 = 6

b) (λx. (λx.x+1)) x 5 = (λx.x+1) x 5 = (λx.x+1) 5 = 6

Comment: This looks like a homework question. We aren't here to do your homework for you. We will answer your questions once you've shown us some amount of work on your part.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the ["How to ask a question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: as you ask in the haskell tag - try writing it into haskell (the first is `let f = \ x -> (\ x -> x+1) x` and apply it yourself ;) ...

Comment: btw: there are some parentheses missing ^^

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the haskell tag. If haskell is related then explain *how*.   Your seems like an exercise for a lambda-calculus course, which would be better fit for theoretical sites different from stackoverflow.

Comment: it's just an exercise to check if you understand scope ... so why don't you start and write down the definitions and rules you know?

Comment: @Carsten I get result 6 for both expressions, but I don't think it's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first expression:

```
  (λx. (λx. x + 1) x) 5
= (λx. (λy. y + 1) x) 5 -- alpha renaming
=      (λy. y + 1) 5    -- beta reduction
=           5 + 1       -- beta reduction
=           6
```

The second expression:

```
  ((λx. λx. x + 1) x) 5
= ((λx. λy. y + 1) z) 5 -- alpha renaming (z is a free variable)
= (     λy. y + 1   ) 5 -- beta reduction (z disappears because x is never used)
=           5 + 1       -- beta reduction
=           6
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that answers should be different.One thing that isn't clear to me here, is how could you rename x with z? Isn't it tied variable intfirst lambda?

Comment: No. It's not tied with any lambda. It's a free variable.